# Merges and joins in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I am joining two DataFrame tables that show sums of elements from two different months.

Here is df1:

```
     Query                                        ValueA0
0       IO1_DerivativeReceivables_ChathamLocal    673437.850000
1               IO2_CollateralCalledforReceipt     60000.000000
2          OO1_DerivativePayables_ChathamLocal     73537.550000
```

Here is df2:

```
                   Query                           ValueB0
0       IO1_DerivativeReceivables_ChathamLocal    336705.200000
1               IO2_CollateralCalledforReceipt     20920.000000
2          OO1_DerivativePayables_ChathamLocal     11299.130000
```

Note that the queries are the same, but the values are different.

I tried to join them with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Query')
```

This was my result:

```
 Query                                                   ValueA0     \
0       IO1_DerivativeReceivables_ChathamLocal    673437.850000
1               IO2_CollateralCalledforReceipt     60000.000000
2          OO1_DerivativePayables_ChathamLocal     73537.550000

       ValueB0
0    336705.200000
1     20920.000000
2     11299.130000
```

This is what I was expecting:

```
         Query                                         ValueA0        ValueB0  
0       IO1_DerivativeReceivables_ChathamLocal    673437.850000      336705.200000
1               IO2_CollateralCalledforReceipt     60000.000000      20920.000000
2          OO1_DerivativePayables_ChathamLocal     73537.550000      11299.130000
```

How do I do this? The join seems fairly simple. I have tried several variations of joins and always end up with the tables appearing as though they are separated. Is this correct?

Comment: What is the difference between the two outputs?

Comment: If there isn't a difference then I don't have a problem. It just didn't seem like the expected outcome based on all the examples about joins that I saw online.

Comment: Have u tried to see one entry from the final data frame?

Comment: Chandran Suri, how do I do that?

Comment: According to me it's just that the table cannot be fitted in a single window that's why it is showing it that way. Otherwise your query is correct and the final data frame is the same as what you desire it to be.. it's the same...

Comment: It still looks that way if I expact the window. I'm confused because ValueB0 has its own set of numbers on the left side.

Comment: You can confirm by just outputting any one tuple from the final data frame formed.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Just store the merged datframe in another variable.
Let the variable be fin_df. Then write.
fin_df(0)... Change the braces to square ones.
What you get?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153807/discussion-between-ifthenifthen-and-chandan-suri).

Comment: Nevermind, work blocks chat. I get a lot of key errors.

Comment: does variable[0] work for dataframes, however?

Comment: try `df.loc[0]`

Comment: Thank you Marvin, it works.

Comment: add this line to before your code `pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)`

Comment: Much better!!!!!

Comment: If you answer with that, I'll give you credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this. I had a datframe and it showed me like this, but the datframe was one intact data frame...

[image: see this you may get some idea]

Answer (score 0):

The join is correct - no further information is needed.